# Haskell make a list of the variables of a list

Tags: list, haskell

Suppose I have the data

```
data Expense = MkExpense Double String deriving (Eq,Ord)
```

and a function

```
balanced :: [Expense] -> Double -> Bool
balanced expenses epsilon =
  let amounts = ...
  in maximum amounts - minimum amounts < epsilon;
```

which computes wether the list of expenses is balances (i.e. everyone paid the same with a maximum difference of epsilon due to floating point errors), the epsilon has a value of 0.01.

The alogrithm is correct, but where the three dots are, I want to extract a list of doubles; i.e. the doubles of all the expenses in my parameter. How can I do that without changing the datatype?

Comment: This isn’t directly related to your question, but I’d strongly advise you not to use floating-point values to represent money. If you use integers instead—an integer number of cents, for example, if you’re dealing with U.S. currency—then you will no longer have to worry about things like the epsilon in your example: you can add, subtract, and multiply currency values without needing to worry about rounding or things like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

```
balanced :: [Expense] -> Double -> Bool
balanced expenses epsilon =
  let amounts = map extractExpense expenses
  in maximum amounts - minimum amounts < epsilon
```

And `extractExpense` would be the unwrapper of the `Double` value of your data:

```
extractExpense :: Expense -> Double
extractExpense (MkExpense expense _) = expense
```

Or more concise:

```
balanced :: [Expense] -> Double -> Bool
balanced expenses epsilon =
  let amounts = map extractExpense expenses
  in maximum amounts - minimum amounts < epsilon
    where extractExpense (MkExpense e _) = e
```

Comment: Using record syntax would also create the `extractExpense` function for you.